# Making microsoft word replace work with wildcards?

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I am editing a huge document and using the wildcard search of `. [A-z]` and finding what lines do **not** have a double space after the period. This works great.  How do I easily do a replace command that does NOT change the letter, but merely adds another space?  I am thinking something like `.  [A-z]` but that actually types [A-z].

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I easily do a replace command that does NOT change the letter?

> I am thinking something like `. [A-z]` but that actually replaces `[A-z]` with the matched letter.

You need to use the `()` (Grouping) expression, together with the `\` (Placeholder) expression.

Something like the following.

Search for:

```
. ([A-z])
```

Replace with:

```
.  \1
```

---

#### ( )

> Round brackets have no effect on the search pattern, but are used to
>   divide the pattern into logical sequences where you wish to
>   re-assemble those sequences in a different order during the replace –
>   or to replace only part of that sequence. They must be used in pairs
>   and are addressed by number in the replacement e.g.
>
> `(John) (Smith)` replaced by `\2 \1` (note the spaces in the search
>   and replace strings) – will produce `Smith John`
>
> or replaced by `\2` alone will give `Smith`.
>
> Note: The placeholders `\1`, `\2` etc., can also be used in the search
>   string to identify recurring text. e.g.
>
> Fred Fred could be written `(Fred) \1`.
>
> Round brackets are perhaps the most useful aspect of complex wildcard
>   search and replace operations.

Source [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm)

Comment: Woah, thanks I think this is what I need.  I don't really get what the /1 is actually telling the program though.  Does it refer to the first ()?

One more question for you, how would I do the same search, but looking after a ? symbol - since ? is a wildcard operator?  Something like '? [A-z]' but this doesn't work.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user3466986 Yes the ``\`` is what matched inside the `()` expression. `?` is a wild card (that matches a single character). So if you want to match a real `?` you need to escape it using `\?`. It is all explained in the link in the answer.

Comment: Yeah this i what I needed, thanks.  If I need more help how can I get in touch with you?

Comment: @user3466986 Just ask a new question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for `(\.)( )([A-z])` and replace it with `\1  \3`.

Note: there are two spaces between `\1` and `\3`.